# Regex Extract in Hive (reqexp_extract)

Tags: regex, hiveql

My regex is:

```
(\bosName=(.iPhone.OS.|.Android.))|(?:\b(taAppVersion=)[0-9.]+)|(TAiApp|TATabletApp|TAaApp)
```

My String is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14A456 Mobile iPhone TAiApp TARX13 taAppVersion=161107060 appLang=en_UK osName='iPhone OS' deviceName=iPhone8,4 osVer=10.0.2 taAppVersionString=18.4 mcc=234 mnc=15 connection=cellular
```

I want to grab:

```
osName='iPhone OS' taAppVersion=161107060 TAiApp
```

My regex works in the tester but when I do a Hive Query I just get TAiApp from  it, i also give 0 to capture all groups to regexp_extract().

Thanks!

Comment: *My regex works in the tester*... Did you double the backslashes? `\b` => `\\b`

Comment: Still just gives me one of those capture groups, not all

Comment: Those are not capture groups, those are alternations : you need 3 executions of the regex to capture all the data. Remove the pipes (replace them with `\s+`?) between the 3 parts and you should be fine.

Comment: \s+? is whitespace character, it doesn't help

Comment: @SanilJain you're matching `(a)|(b)|(c)` against a string `"a b c"`. The first execution will return `a` in the first group, which is what you're getting. The second would return `b` in the second group, the third `c` in the third group. If you want to retrieve all of them with a single match you need to stop using alternation (pipes, `|`) ; in that example's case, that would be replacing the pipes by spaces : `(a) (b) (c)` would return `a`, `b` and `c` in their respective groups with a single match.